# dynamic javascript URL query generation based on if input data is selected on form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build some Javascript code where basically I'm generating query urls based on what fields on the form the user inputs.

In short there are certain fields that are required and certain fields that are optional.

Based on what the users types in, that is how the URL will be generated.

Currently my URL generation is fixed meaning that it can't remove option query searches but I'm trying to figure out a way to make the query based on the form input the user makes to be more dynamic.

IE: My variable for generating the form looks like this:

```
var ObjectData = JSON.parse(db.connectionData),dataString = "key=" + ObjectData.key + "&Symbol" + ObjectData.Symbol + "&startDate=" + ObjectData.startDate + "&endDate=" + ObjectData.endDate, apiCall="https://myurl.com/getMyDataNow.json?" + dataString;
```

I've already build the javascript to check that all required forms (symbol, key) are required, however, if I try to leave the other variables (startDate, endDate) blank then I get a break in my code because the URL query can't handle empty fields on the html form.

I'm trying to see if there is a way to build logical around the var Object so it will parse certain fields that are blank when generating the query.

Right now it always tries to create a URL that has all of the fields below:
https://myurl.com/getMyDataNow.json?key=x&Symbol=x&startDate=x&endDate=x

I think this is why its breaking but I can't figure out how to make this more dynamic to look at what fields are blank and just remove them before generating url. IE: if I leave startDate blank on the form it will simply generate:
https://myurl.com/getMyDataNow.json?key=x&Symbol=x&endDate=x

Unsure how to generate dynamic url queries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take advantage of [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
const ObjectData = {
  key: "1",
  Symbol: "2",
  startDate: "3",
  endDate: "4",
};

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(ObjectData);
const apiCall = `https://myurl.com/getMyDataNow.json?${searchParams}`;
console.log(apiCall);
```

Or [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL):

```js
const ObjectData = {
  key: "1",
  Symbol: "2",
  startDate: "3",
  endDate: "4",
};

const url = new URL("https://myurl.com/getMyDataNow.json");

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ObjectData)) {
  url.searchParams.set(key, value);
}

console.log(url.href);
```

Comment: Thanks URL search parameters worked somewhat. I do have issues with now some parameters not working if they are selected (or not). I will post another message about this.